# Code works in console but not when saved to file

Tags: python, console

The exact same code works in the Python Console but not when saved to a file. The `if` statements definitely get executed (I have checked by `print`ing statements inside them).

```
import re


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        pwd = input("Enter your password: ")
        if not re.findall(r"[a-z]", pwd):
            span = re.search(r"[A-Z]", pwd)
            re.sub(pwd[span.start():span.end()],
                   pwd[span.start():span.end()].lower(), pwd)
        if not re.findall(r"[A-Z]", pwd):
            span = re.search(r"[a-z]", pwd)
            re.sub(pwd[span.start():span.end()],
                   pwd[span.start():span.end()].upper(), pwd)
        print(pwd)
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: I don't think that backslash should be there in the penultimate line

Comment: @Sayse it gives back the password without any modification. This is a shortened version of a slightly bigger file, the rest of the functionality works, just not this part.

Comment: `re.sub` doesn't modify the password in-place. Do `pwd= re.sub(...)`. It may look like it works in an interactive session, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Rawing that worked. The way it happened in the Python Console it seemed that it substitutes it automatically.

Comment: @Neel: It doesn't. The console automatically prints the value returned by the last command you entered, if it isn't None.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons can be:

- CR/LF at the end of lines. Python recommends simple LF.
- TAB/SPACES: maybe your IDE replaces your white spaces. Python recommends simple spaces for ident.

Please write the error message/ detailed behaviour

Comment: This should be a comment, it doesn't answer the question.